# printing UTF8String in XCode Debugger Console

Tags: xcode, gdb

While printing contents of a NSTextField the debugger is displaying following character sequence \342\200\250 for newline. Can anyone tell me how to interpret this sequence, I expect it to be newline character since I entered newline after Headline news 1

print (Ptr)[[sender objectValue] UTF8String]
$15 = 0x14a1b0 "Headline news 1\342\200\250Headline news 2\342\200\250Headline news 3\342\200\250Headline news 4"

Also po [sender objectValue] outputs something like this

(gdb) po [sender objectValue]
Headline news 1 
    Headline news 2 
    Headline news 3
     Headline news 4

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\342\200\250` (specifically, the bytes with values `0342 = 0xe2`, `0200 = 0x80`, and `0250 = 0xa8`) is the UTF-8 encoding of Unicode character U+2028, named "LINE SEPARATOR".  The newline that you entered is being interpreted as U+2028 for some reason, and then it is encoded as UTF-8 and printed out as a series of octal escapes.